# Can I specify that Web-Api method expects a file in Swashbuckle/Swagger generated page/json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I got a Web-Api with the following simplified method for obtaining a file:

```
[HttpPut("Test/{id}")]
public IActionResult PutTest(string id)
{
    Stream file = Request.Body;
    //rest of method
    return StatusCode(201);
}
```

It works fine, although in the `SwaggerUI` page that gets created there's no mention of the method expecting a file in the body. Is there a way to specify the method expects a file in the generated `SwaggerUI` page?

I can simulate the input using the following piece of code:

```
var content = new StreamContent(new FileStream("C:\temp\test.txt", FileMode.Open));

using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var response = client.PutAsync(url, content))
{
    var result = response.Result;
    //more code   
}
```

Comment: I think this may be helpful: https://alexdunn.org/2018/07/12/adding-a-file-upload-field-to-your-swagger-ui-with-swashbuckle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file upload is not documented because it's not a param in the action method. Swagger has no way of knowing what you're doing inside the action itself. Attempting to handle a file upload this way is bad practice anyways. You can use `IFormFile`, but that only works if your request body is encoded as `multipart/form-data`. If you're dealing with JSON or basically anything that qualifies as `FromBody`, then you need to bind to a `byte[]`:

```
[HttpPut("Test/{id}")]
public IActionResult PutTest(string id, byte[] file)
{
    //rest of method
    return StatusCode(201);
}
```

Now, the automatic `FromBody` applied by the `[ApiController]` attribute only works with class types, so I'm not sure off the top of my head whether it will apply to a `byte[]`. If not, just do:

```
public IActionResult PutTest(string id, [FromBody]byte[] file)
```

Comment: That's what I meant. You send it as a JSON string, just as if you were trying to `FromBody` bind a `string` param. Like I said, I've never tried that in particular, but I can state for a fact that as a member of a JSON object, this is *totally* supported.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can get it working like that, but it's also not compatible with the input I get.

Comment: Well, it's an API: it defines the input, not the other way around. However, I'd need more info about your particular scenario, to provide further guidance.

Comment: True, it shouldn't be the API that has to adjust. I'll go with the `IFormFile`, which just seems like the best solution and else Swagger just doesn't show it.